# Python create nested dict in for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to created a nested dictionary but I have a problem inside the for loop, at least is what I'm thinking.
I do several requests based on args passed but when I try to add values to the nested dict created before it just adds the last arg passed.
I'll show the code and the output.

```py
def api_metrics():
    my_list = []
    my_dict_1 = {}
    number = len(my_metrics)
    metricz = range(number)
    for indice in metricz:
        my_dict_1[indice] = {}
    for metric in my_metrics:
        urlnotoken = ""
        urlnotoken = urlnotoken.replace(" ","%20")
        preurl = urlnotoken + "&dateToken="+expirationDate
        msg = preurl + apikey
        token = calcMd5(msg)
        finalurl = "http://"+host+preurl+"&token="+token
        data_get = requests.get(finalurl, headers=app_headers)
        json_data = json.loads(data_get.text)
        metrics_path = json_data['data'][0]['metrics'][0]
        metric_name = metrics_path['label']
        metric_value = metrics_path['values'][0]['data'][0][1]
        metric_unit = metrics_path['magnitudes']['y']
        my_list.append(metric_name)
        my_list.append(metric_value)
        my_list.append(metric_unit)
        number = len(my_metrics)
        metricz = range(number)
        my_values = metric
        for entry in my_dict_1.keys():
          my_dict_1[entry] = metric
    return(my_dict_1)
```

And the output

```
{0: 'avgRenditionSwitchTime', 1: 'avgRenditionSwitchTime', 2: 'avgRenditionSwitchTime', 3: 'avgRenditionSwitchTime', 4: 'avgRenditionSwitchTime'}"
```

This should output the different args passed. I have moved the code inside and outside the loop, I've read lots of posts but I need further help!

Cheers.

Comment: you could benefit from reading on list and dictionary comprehension in first. also please stick to indentation levels - this is tagged as python not java - so indentation matters

Comment: I've read and still don't making it. 
Regarding to indentation I just see one out of line and it was rearranged here so it might have escaped, and it is indeed python, now can you actually help ? It seems well ident now.

Comment: you should get rid of this first:  for indice in metricz:
        my_dict_1[indice] = {} use enumerate, use comprehension; this will help to clean up your code

Comment: Thanks, going to give a look

Comment: Fix your code indentation since it's causing confusion with you and everybody else. Also try to improve your question as well.

Comment: Still can’t understand your problem with indentation. I’ll reup the code. It has 2 spaces and in the for loop 4 spaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here:

```
for entry in my_dict_1.keys():
    my_dict_1[entry] = metric
```

You are assigning the value of `metric` to all your `dict` (`my_dict_1`) items. Reason why 'it just adds the last arg passed'.

Without cleaning up your code, here's the patch to fix your issue:

```
for i, metric in enumerate(my_metrics):
    ...
    my_dict_1[i] = metric
```

Comment: But the metric values are the args passed, if I do print(metric) it prints everything. I know the problem is mine but I’m having hard time to understand

Comment: With every argument passed in you iterate through your `dict` and reassign the same arg value to all the dict elements.

Comment: I can see what you are saying, nice. Can you give me some hints on what to search in order to accomplish what I’m trying to do?

Comment: Thank you! I wasn’t expecting the right answer I was looking for tips and yours and drakos helped me a lot. 
I just googled some articles on dictionary comprehension  and enumerate!